# Modifying my Code to Have Methods Acting on Objects

Tags: java, oop, object, constructor

This is my code so far:

```
public class Word{

  String text;

  public Word(String text){
    this.text = text;
  }

  public static boolean isPalindrome(Word word){

    char[] text1 = new char[word.text.length()];

    for(int i = 0; i< word.text.length(); i++){
      text1[i] = word.text.charAt(i);
    }
    char[] text2 = new char[word.text.length()];
    int j = 0;
    for(int i = word.text.length()-1; i >=0; i--){
      text2[j] = word.text.charAt(i);
      j++;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < word.text.length(); i++){
      if(text2[i]!=text1[i]){
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){

    Word word = new Word("racecar");

    System.out.println(isPalindrome(word));

  }
}
```

## The Goal

It works but I'm trying to rewrite my code to somehow pass in the object and have the method act on it. So the method should take in no inputs and I should be able to write `object.isPalindrome()` and have it output the `boolean`.

This isn't for a homework or anything. Just wanted to further challenge myself as I'm pretty weak with objects.

Comment: well, it's not really challenging your self if other people are doing it for you. maybe you may want to start here --> [Lesson: Classes and Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html)

Comment: Look up the `this` keyword

Comment: I believe OP want to make `isPalindrome()` method ***non-static***.

Comment: (1) remove `static`  (2) `System.out.println(word.isPalindrome());`

Comment: @PM77-1 Yea that. I know that making it non-static allows it to act specifically on an object but doing so would also mean modifying the method to not accept any arguments. In that case, how would I be able to execute the method correctly if no input is being used to identify if the word is a palindrome? It does work if I make it non-static and keep it as System.out.println(word.isPalindrome(word)) but that seems inefficient to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simply, instead of using `word`, use [`this`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html), which refers to the object the method is called on. Then you need to remove the `static` keyword. So something like:

```
public boolean isPalindrome(){

    char[] text1 = new char[this.text.length()];

    for(int i = 0; i< this.text.length(); i++){
       text1[i] = this.text.charAt(i);
    }
    char[] text2 = new char[this.text.length()];
    int j = 0;
    for(int i = this.text.length()-1; i >=0; i--){
       text2[j] = this.text.charAt(i);
       j++;
    } 

    for(int i = 0; i < this.text.length(); i++){
       if(text2[i]!=text1[i]){
          return false;
       }
    }
    return true;
}
```

And then you can call it as:

```
word.isPalindrome()
```

Answer (score 0):

The following answer is because of the `oop`-tag.

## Your Palindrom algorithm

The steps you are do are:

1. make the `string` to a `char[]`
2. create a reversed `char[]` of the first one
3. compare the two `char[]`

## Rewrite to OOP

### 2. Step of the Algorithm

I just copy & paste your code into a new method  and return a new `Word`.

```
public Word reverse() {
    char[] reversed = new char[text.length()];
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = text.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        reversed[j]= text.charAt(i);
        j++;
    }
    return new Word(String.valueOf(reversed));
}
```

### 3. Step of the Algorithm

Since the method `reverse` returns a new `Word` I need to compare two `Word`-objects. This can be done with the `equals`-method. There for we need to override it from `Object`.

### The Algorithm

```
public boolean isPalindrome() {
    Word reversed = reverse();
    return this.equals(reversed);
}
```

### Where is the 1. Step

We just don't need it here, because we compare two `Word`s and not two `char[]`.

### Full Code

```
public class Word {

    private String text;

    public Word(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public boolean isPalindrome() {
        Word reversed = reverse();
        return this.equals(reversed);
    }

    public Word reverse() {
        char[] reversed = new char[text.length()];
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = text.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            reversed[j]= text.charAt(i);
            j++;
        }
        return new Word(String.valueOf(reversed));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Word word = (Word) o;

        return text != null ? text.equals(word.text) : word.text == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return text != null ? text.hashCode() : 0;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Word{

  String text;

  public Word(String text){
    this.text = text;
  }

  public   boolean isPalindrome(){

    char[] text1 = new char[this.text.length()];

    for(int i = 0; i< this.text.length(); i++){
      text1[i] = this.text.charAt(i);
    }
    char[] text2 = new char[this.text.length()];
    int j = 0;
    for(int i = this.text.length()-1; i >=0; i--){
      text2[j] = this.text.charAt(i);
      j++;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < this.text.length(); i++){
      if(text2[i]!=text1[i]){
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

public static void main(String[] args){
    Word word = new Word("racecar");
    System.out.println(word.isPalindrome());
 }
}
```

the same with static void main function
the whole code ;)

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.